# SQLException: Cannot Open Database requested by the login, the login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server

Quiero hacer una api en ASPNet Core

Ese usuario no tiene contraseña, estoy autenticandome con el usuario de windows al hacer una peticion, no se puede hacer la consulta y me arroja este error:

```
SqlException: Cannot open database "PlantSharingContext-a60299d5-c7a1-45b7-9cb5-f744773cd64e" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '09DENAH1\Direccion ENAH'.
```

¿Alguien podría decirme a que se debe eso y que debería hacer para solucionarlo?

El controlador lo hice con scaffold, seleccione el modelo que quería que ese controlador manejara y el DBContext que iba a gestionar el modelo de datos.

Debería agregar el usuario a la cadena de conexión?

La cadena de conexión es esta:

```
 "PlantSharingContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PlantSharingContext-a60299d5-c7a1-45b7-9cb5-f744773cd64e;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

el error es bastante clarom te intentas conectar a SQL Server con un usuario (09DENAH1\Direccion ENAH) es decir el usuario con la que la aplicación está ejecutandose no tiene permisos para acceder a la base de datos.

Debes verificar si en el SQL Server está agregado en la parte de seguridad y roles el usuario de sistema operativo ( es decir 09DENAH1\Direccion ENAH) y que el usuario tenga permisos de conección y de acceso a los registros.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es crear un usuario de bases de datos (que no sea usuario de sistema operativo).

por ejemplo: **Ramirito** con clave:**123**

para ello tu cadena de conección debería ser:

```
"PlantSharingContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=PlantSharingContext-a60299d5-c7a1-45b7-9cb5-f744773cd64e;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=Ramirito;pwd=123"
```

Tomado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575907/cannot-open-database-test-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fail

Para ello debes usar algo como esto:

CREATE LOGIN **Ramirito**
WITH PASSWORD = '123';
GO

CREATE USER **Ramirito** FOR LOGIN **Ramirito**;
GO

Luego en el Manager le agregas los permisos a el usuario **Ramirito**